# PHP to JSON encoding

Tags: php, json

I am trying to write this using php and json_encode

```
{"patient": {"demographics": {}}
```

}

This is the Array I am using with json encode.

```
Array("patient" =>  Array("demographics" =>  Array()))
```

When I echo the output, this is what I get:

```
{"patient":{"demographics":[]}}
```

I really think this is a stupid mistake ob my part. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
json_encode($your_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

as per the docs: http://php.net/json_encode

By default, php arrays stay arrays (`[]`) when json'd, unless there's a single non-numeric key, in which case it'll be an object

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
json_encode(Array("patient" =>  Array("demographics" => new stdClass)));
```

This way you can have empty arrays and empty objects in the same JSON, which would not be possible using the other answer.